# How to connect GWT to Oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle, gwt, jdbc

I'm new to **GWT**. I'm trying to connect my `Oracle10g` database to GWT server program,
I'm using this code:

```
public class Database_connect
{   
    public static void connect() 
    {
        System.out.println("This is a test project");
        Connection con=null;

        try 
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE","naren", "naren");
            System.out.println("Connected with @localhost:1521:XE.");
            System.out.println("We have done it successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

in server file i'm calling the `connect()` function

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService
{
    public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        Database_connect.connect();
    }
}
```

but it's showing error.

I don't know what to do now. Anyone help me. Thanks for advance.

the error is

```
[WARN] failed Server@6e058516
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:205)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:304)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:233)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartupServer method
```

Comment: I'd recommend showing the error to get past this issue.  It's not clear to me what you'd like to do, but I'm certain that this is not the way to go.  You should not have connection code hard wired into your Java source this way.  It's more typical to let an app server deal with those connection parameters and abstract the data source.

Comment: Unchecked exceptions are never written in a `throws`.

Comment: but that line is working when i'm doing something else instead of Database_connect.connect(); function call

Answer (score 0):

You are running  the project 2 times i think ..please kill all the java processes in task manager and run the project only once ..

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what led you to that conclusion, e.g., explaining that the port already in use mean the server has been started.